# KVM guests don't show correct source IP

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, networkmanager

I've got KVM hosted on CentOS 7. All of my networking configurations are done via NetworkManager. 
The problem I'm facing is that guests show KVM's IP, rather than my external IP, when connecting to them, i.e. via SSH, from external networks.

Guests networking is set to virbr1, routed to enp2s0, where they are then NAT'ed before going to external networks.

KVM LAN IP - 192.168.1.1/24

`firewall-cmd list-all` output:

```
external (active)                                                                                                                                                                            
  target: default                                                                                                                                                                            
  icmp-block-inversion: no                                                                                                                                                                   
  interfaces: enp2s0                                                                                                                                                                         
  sources:                                                                                                                                                                                   
  services: ssh                                                                                                                                                                              
  ports:                                                                                                                                                                                     
  protocols:                                                                                                                                                                                 
  masquerade: yes                                                                                                                                                                            
  forward-ports:                                                                                                                                                                             
  source-ports:                                                                                                                                                                              
  icmp-blocks:                                                                                                                                                                               
  rich rules:     
      rule family="ipv4" source ipset="whitelist" forward-port port="2222" protocol="tcp" to-port="22" to-addr="192.168.1.2"

..
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0 virbr1
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

`systemctl status iptables` output:

```
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

`iptables -vnL` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)                                                                                                                                               
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67                                                                                          
16402 2196K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                
 2478  130K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                             
 2477  130K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                       
 2477  130K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                              
   17  1068 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID                                                                                     
 2298  112K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited                                                                    

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)                                                                                                                                             
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable                                                                   
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable                                                                   
17830  153M ACCEPT     all  --  enp2s0 virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24                                                                                                           
12801   18M ACCEPT     all  --  virbr1 enp2s0  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr1 virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable                                                                   
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable                                                                   
    1    69 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                
 2319  114K FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                           
 2319  114K FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                  
 2319  114K FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                         
 2317  114K FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                 
 2317  114K FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                        
    5   204 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID                                                                                     
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited                                                                    

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 20270 packets, 15M bytes)                                                                                                                                        
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68                                                                                          
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68                                                                                          
20272   15M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)                                                                                                                                                        
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
 2319  114K FWDI_external  all  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]                                                                                           
    0     0 FWDI_trusted  all  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                             
    0     0 FWDI_trusted  all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                             
    0     0 FWDI_external  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]                                                                                           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)                                                                                                                                                 
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)                                                                                                                                                       
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
 2317  114K FWDO_external  all  --  *      enp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]                                                                                           
    0     0 FWDO_trusted  all  --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                             
    0     0 FWDO_trusted  all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                             
    0     0 FWDO_external  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]                                                                                           

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)                                                                                                                                                
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)                                                                                                                                                          
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDI_external (2 references)                                                                                                                                                           
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
 2319  114K FWDI_external_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                        
 2319  114K FWDI_external_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                       
 2319  114K FWDI_external_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                      
    2    62 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                

Chain FWDI_external_allow (1 references)                                                                                                                                                     
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x64                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x65                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x66                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x67                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x68                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x69                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x6a                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x6b                                                                         

Chain FWDI_external_deny (1 references)                                                                                                                                                      
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDI_external_log (1 references)                                                                                                                                                       
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDI_trusted (2 references)                                                                                                                                                            
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
    0     0 FWDI_trusted_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                         
    0     0 FWDI_trusted_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                        
    0     0 FWDI_trusted_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                       
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                

Chain FWDI_trusted_allow (1 references)                                                                                                                                                      
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDI_trusted_deny (1 references)                                                                                                                                                       
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDI_trusted_log (1 references)                                                                                                                                                        
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDO_external (2 references)                                                                                                                                                           
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
 2317  114K FWDO_external_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                        
 2317  114K FWDO_external_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                       
 2317  114K FWDO_external_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                      

Chain FWDO_external_allow (1 references)                                                                                                                                                     
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
 2312  113K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW                                                                                         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW                                                                                         

Chain FWDO_external_deny (1 references)                                                                                                                                                      
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDO_external_log (1 references)                                                                                                                                                       
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDO_trusted (2 references)                                                                                                                                                            
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
    0     0 FWDO_trusted_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                         
    0     0 FWDO_trusted_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                        
    0     0 FWDO_trusted_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                       
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                                

Chain FWDO_trusted_allow (1 references)                                                                                                                                                      
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDO_trusted_deny (1 references)                                                                                                                                                       
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain FWDO_trusted_log (1 references)                                                                                                                                                        
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)                                                                                                                                                             
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                                              
 2415  119K IN_external  all  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]                                                                                             
   62 11515 IN_trusted  all  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 IN_trusted  all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 IN_external  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    60 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22 match-set fail2ban-sshd src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain IN_external (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2415  119K IN_external_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2415  119K IN_external_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2415  119K IN_external_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   40  2682 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_external_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   60  3056 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_external_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_external_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_trusted (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   62 11515 IN_trusted_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   62 11515 IN_trusted_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   62 11515 IN_trusted_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   62 11515 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_trusted_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_trusted_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_trusted_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

`nmcli con show virbr1` output (cropped):

```
connection.id:                          virbr1                                                                                                                                               
connection.uuid:                        42f97b7c-40f0-4c3a-9a39-cf8d6af8bb12
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        bridge
connection.interface-name:              virbr1
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.1.1/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
```

Comment: If you want your guest using an IP in your hypervisor subnet, then you shouln't use virbrX, which is an internal bridge. Instead, make sure your hypervisor main interface is a bridge, then map your guest NIC to that bridge instead.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear on the issue, what I meant was if I connect using an external IP 1.2.3.4, it shows up as 192.168.1.1, which is KVM's gateway to the guests, instead of the aforementioned 1.2.3.4